Is this the right procedure to make your way to the door for an evacuation?
After watching this video of an evacuation training and the hilarious recreation of the youtuber on the second part of the video, I couldn't help but think about this seriously, it just doesn't look right to me, it just looks like the FA is going to hurt someone(specially in a situation with urgency and poor visibility: smoke in the cabin, loss of ambient light, etc)
Is that the right procedure?


Yes, this is the correct way, although some variations exist depending on training.
First of all you must realize that the first and foremost task of cabin crew is not to serve meals and beveages. What majority of their training aims at is them basically being able to act as an efficient riot police task force when the doodoo hits the fan.
In the video in question the FA quite efficiently uses both aural and physical language, accompanied by good eye contact. The purpose of this combination is to establish dominance in the panicking and irrational passengers to ensure they can be managed and safely evacutated.
And in case you are wondering: yes, she will jab you with the elbow if you don't make way.

Understood, didn't knew that elbow technique was part of the oficial training. It does make sense to use it to put in their place the ones that go irrational, I just thought there was something more 'friendly'/less aggressive yet at the same time efficient.

@Gabe in non-emergency situations the cabin crew will be polite. For example an unexpected but not time critical disembarkation would be one. But in a real emergency, efficiency will kick the manners out of the plane. They need to have your full attention and compliance and they certainly have the means

Are you sure? I mean, yelling "outta my way" continuously, and hitting non-compliant passengers with her elbow? Also, she doesn't look too calm to me; I sense a bit of a panicked expression, although I may be mistaken.

@AircraftEnthusiast007 yes I am sure.
